# Postgres trigger after insert accessing NEW

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a pretty simple trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_log_datei()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO logs (aktion, tabelle, benutzer_id) VALUES(TG_OP, 'dateien', NEW.benutzer_id);
END; $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER log_datei AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON dateien
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_log_datei();
```

My table logs is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE logs(
    id int PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXTVAL('logs_id_seq'),
    zeit timestamp DEFAULT now(),
    aktion char(6),
    tabelle varchar(32),
    alt varchar(256),
    neu varchar(256),
    benutzer_id int references benutzer(id)
);
```

After inserting something in dateien I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  record "new" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO logs (aktion, tabelle, benutzer_id) VALUES(TG_OP, 'dateien', NEW.benutzer_id)"
PL/pgSQL function "f_log_datei" line 3 at SQL statement
```

Why did I get this error? I looked into the documentation and it seems they use new in the same way I do.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/trigger-definition.html):

> **36.1. Overview of Trigger Behavior**
>   [...]
>   For a row-level trigger, the input data also includes the `NEW` row for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers, and/or the `OLD` row for `UPDATE` and `DELETE` triggers. Statement-level triggers do not currently have any way to examine the individual row(s) modified by the statement.

And from [Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> `NEW`
>   Data type `RECORD`; variable holding the new database row for `INSERT`/`UPDATE` operations in row-level triggers. This variable is `NULL` in statement-level triggers and for `DELETE` operations.

Note what it says about row-level triggers and statement-level triggers.

You have a statement-level trigger:

```
...
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_log_datei();
```

Statement-level triggers are triggered once per statement and a statement can apply to multiple rows so the notion of *affected row* (which is what `NEW` and `OLD` are about) simply doesn't apply.

If you want to use `NEW` (or `OLD`) in a trigger then you want the trigger to execute for each affected row and that means you want a row-level trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_datei AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON dateien
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_log_datei();
```

I just changed `FOR EACH STATEMENT` to `FOR EACH ROW`.

---

Your trigger should also [be returning something](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> A trigger function must return either `NULL` or a record/row value having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.
>   [...]
>   The return value of a row-level trigger fired `AFTER` or a statement-level trigger fired `BEFORE` or `AFTER` is always ignored; it might as well be null. However, any of these types of triggers might still abort the entire operation by raising an error.

So you should `RETURN NEW;` or `RETURN NULL;` in your trigger. You have an AFTER trigger so it doesn't matter which RETURN you use but I'd go with `RETURN NEW;`.

Comment: Did you also add `RETURN NEW;` to the end of the function?

Comment: @kgrittn: That would be the *next* bug, no? But yeah, I didn't even see that and it is worth mentioning while we're here.

Comment: yeah I've added the `RETURN` statement :)

Comment: If it is AFTER trigger, you should be using `RETURN NULL`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: @Gajus Any particular reason to choose `null` other than that all the examples use `null`?

Comment: Because AFTER trigger has no effect. Returning `NEW` is misleading at best.