# Postgres SQL trigger to update TableA.column with NEW value AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE on TableB

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, database-trigger

I have a very simple trigger, that updates a column in table_a whenever table_b is updated:

```
create or replace function trigger_update_status()
    returns trigger as 
    $body$
    begin

-- UPDATE TABLE A   
update table_a
    set a_status = new.b_status,
        date_updated = now()
    from table_b
        where table_a.serial_number = table_b.serial_number; 

    return new;

end;
$body$
language plpgsql;

create trigger "currentStatus" after update or insert on table_b
for each row 
execute procedure trigger_update_status();
```

However, I am getting the error that there is no `RETURN` value:

`ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN`

I'm confused on whether or not `NEW` is appropriate here as I've been reading conflicting information. 
On the one hand, the answer here ([Postgres trigger after insert accessing NEW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001118/postgres-trigger-after-insert-accessing-new)) makes it clear that: *"The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null. However, any of these types of triggers might still abort the entire operation by raising an error."*

On the other hand, my trigger here essentially matches the one here (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182678/postgresql-trigger-to-update-a-column-in-a-table-when-another-table-gets-inserte), which calls `NEW` & `AFTER` together. So I am not sure why mine is not working. Any help is very greatly appreciated!

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=39d331fc9a8254366b84a143e1ee3f77

Answer (score 0):

Future answer for anybody with same issue: it was a second (similarly named, which is why I didn't catch it until much later) trigger that was called AFTER this one that was causing the issue. The second trigger could not `RETURN NEW` because in this case, there was no new value. I fixed this by adding an `IF/ELSE` statement to my second trigger:

```
IF NEW.current_location <> OLD.current_location 
    THEN
    INSERT INTO table_x(serial_number, foo, bar)
        VALUES(OLD.serial_number, OLD.foo, old.bar);
    return new;

-- ADDED THIS LINE: 
    else return null;
END IF;
```

Lesson learned thanks to @sticky bit - if the trigger works in an isolated dbfiddle, it's something else causing the issue.