# CREATE with DEFAULT based on first id of another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

An, i hope, simple question i sadly can't find the answer to trough googling or RTFMing.

I want to create a column with a default value that is based in the first id of another table.

Something like that, which sadly gives me "ERROR:  cannot use subquery in default expression"

```
ALTER TABLE foobar 
      ADD COLUMN foo INTEGER DEFAULT (SELECT id FROM blubb LIMIT 1);
```

The problem is, I can not simply assume that 'blubb' starts at 0 or 1 and I want to put a CONSTRAINT on it later on.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` does not mean the "first" id. It means "just 1 row, any row". Until you provide an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Do you want to be the default value to be the value of blubb.id **on install time** of the table foobar (i.e. when you execute your `ALTER TABLE` command), or the value of blubb.id **on inserting** a new value into foobar?

Comment: On inserting, please.

Comment: That kind of assignment is done in a trigger, not in a `default` clause. See [Postgresql insert trigger to set value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16102188/238814)

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do that? It sounds like a rather strange requirement. Maybe there is a better solution to your *actual* problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer:  Use a function.

Example:

```
  CREATE TABLE foo (id serial primary key);

  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION max_foo() RETURNS int LANGUAGE SQL AS
  $$ SELECT max(id) FROM foo; $$;

  CREATE TABLE bar(id int not null default max_foo());
```