# SQLAlchemy: how should I define a column's default value computed using a reference to the table containing that column?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy: how should I define a column's default value computed using a reference to the table containing that column?

Let's use these tables as an example (SQLite):

```
CREATE TABLE department (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE employee (
  id INTEGER,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  department_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES department(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id, department_id)
);
```

I want each eployee's ID to be unique only with respect to their department. On `INSERT`, a new employee ID should be generated that is one larger than the previously-highest employee ID in that department.

Put in raw SQL, here's what I'm looking to do:

```
INSERT INTO employee(
    id,
    name,
    department_id
)
VALUES (
    (
        SELECT coalesce(MAX(id),0)+1
        FROM employee
        WHERE department_id=?
    ),
    ?,
    ?
)
```

What's the best way to do this using SQLAlchemy?

I think I'm looking for something similar to the third column example [in here.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#sql-expressions) Something like this:

```
employee_table = Table("employee", meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False,
      default=keyvalues.select(
        func.max(employee_table.c.id)
      ).filter_by(department_id=??))
    Column('department_id', Integer, ForeignKey('department.id'),
        nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    Column('name', String(127), nullable=False),
    )
```

That doesn't work, of course: I don't have a reference to the `employee` table yet (since I'm still defining it) and because I don't know how to reference the "current" `department_id` in the `filter_by` clause. (There are quite possibly other problems, too)

Alternatively, if it is not possible to do this through the Python API, is there any way I can just specify a column's default value (applied at `INSERT` time) using raw SQL? Or do i need to use raw SQL for the entire insert?

Note: my situation is basically the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783509/sqlalchemy-postgresql-database-column-computed-default-value), but the solution I'm looking for is different: I want to use a nested `SELECT` in my inserts rather than create a DB trigger.

**EDIT**

I'm getting closer to solving the problem, but I'm still not there yet.

`agronholm` in `#sqlalchemy` explained that by just using `default` there would be no way to fill in the `department_id` because although it's possible to have the selectable used as the default on `INSERT`, there is no way to fill in *parameters* (the `department_id`)

Instead, `agronholm` suggested the best solution is to create the subquery within the constructor. By assigning the query (not running it and assigning the result!), the id will be fetched in a sub-`SELECT`. This avoids the race condition that would result from performing the `SELECT` first on the Python side, and then assigning the result.

I'm trying out something like this:

```
def __init__(self, department, name):
    self.id = db.select(
        db.func.max(Employee.id)
    ).filter_by(department_id=department.id).as_scalar()
    self.department = department
    self.data = data
```

Unfortunately, this also doesn't work, because the calculated column is used as part of the primary key. It throws:

```
InvalidRequestError: Instance <XXXXX at 0x3d15d10> cannot be refreshed - it's not  persistent and does not contain a full primary key.
```

In my original raw-SQLite version, I would access the newly-created row with the cursor's `lastrowid`. Is something similar possible in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: "unique on `ID`" is a stronger than "unique on `ID`, `DeptID`",  is there some reason you want multiple, distinct employees to have the *same* employee ID, or is it only that you don't care if they do?

Comment: I am looking for a solution to this, too. For me your approach didn't work. In my case the column in question is part of a primary key and I get the error message: `InvalidRequestError: Instance <XXXXX at 0x3d15d10> cannot be refreshed - it's not  persistent and does not contain a full primary key.`

Comment: @room2web unfortunately I ran into the same problem. I've just updated the question. Please report back if you find a solution!

Comment: @IfLoop I should have noted that I just used employees/departments as an example. It may not have been the best choice, since employee IDs should almost certainly be globally unique. The real use case is a bit more complex: the child table stores a number of distinct categories of objects, where it would never make sense for an object to migrate between categories. While per-category IDs still aren't strictly needed, we'd like them mainly for aesthetic reasons: the IDs are publicly visible in a REST API (/<category_name>/<item_id>), and we'd prefer that they increase in unit increments

Comment: @GabrielGrant after asking in the IRC channel I took the issue to the Google Group. Let's hope they can help us :).

Comment: @room2web great, thanks! Looks like this is the thread, if anyone else is curious: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/LsY1QmR-neI

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and finally arrived at this solution. There's still room for improvement -- it does the SELECT before the INSERT rather than inlining it -- but it seems to work.

```
from sqlalchemy import sql

...

def default_employee_id(context):
    return context.connection.execute(
        sql.select(
            [sql.func.ifnull(sql.func.max(employee_table.c.id), 0) + 1]
        ).where(
            employee_table.c.department_id==context.current_parameters['department_id']
        )
    ).scalar()

employee_table = Table("employee", meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False,
      default=default_employee_id),
    Column('department_id', Integer, ForeignKey('department.id'),
        nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
    Column('name', String(127), nullable=False)
)
```

The next thing I would try is a [trigger](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/defaults.html?highlight=triggered#triggered-columns), even though the docs say it's a bad idea for a primary key.
Hooking into the "before_flush" event would probably have the same pre-select issue.
It may also be possible to alter or replace context.compiled argument in order to inject the SELECT into the INSERT, but that seems extreme for what we're trying to accomplish.