# How can I create a sqlalchemy column whose default is to be equal to the primary key?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, primary-key

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Foo(Base):
    pk = Column(Integer, Sequence('foo'), primary_key=True)
```

I want to make another field, `ref`, that defaults to being equal to `pk` for newly-created objects. Unfortunately, I'm using Postgres, which has a [non-standard `nextval()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/2d29c570-bc21-41ed-9914-2a456fc3ea6c@mm), so I can't simply make both of the columns default to the Sequence object.

Here's my current solution:

```
class Foo(Base):
    pk = Column(Integer, Sequence('foo'), primary_key=True)
    ref = Column(Integer, index=True, nullable=False, default=func.currval('foo'))
```

However this depends on two things: SQLAlchemy generating an INSERT statement with `pk` before `ref`, *and* Postgres evaluating expressions from left to right (so the `nextval()` call generated by `pk` always happens before the `currval` call generated by `ref`).

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions for how to do this better!

EDIT: There's also the more solution of setting `default=-1` or something and forcing the caller to update the `ref` field. That's safer and more robust to changes in SQLA/Postgres semantics but pretty inconvenient for clients of the class.

Comment: what's the problem that this solves?  Are you making a "heirarchy" schema?

Comment: We're introducing versioning of the object and need to maintain compatibility with an old version of our client app.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how one relates to the other.  does `Foo.ref` "point to" another tuple in `Foo`?  What does the connection mean?  How will it be queried?

Comment: I appreciate your urge to solve the larger problem here, but it involves quite a bit of context to explain and we're already exploring a bunch of different alternatives. I would really just like to know if there's a way to get SQLAlchemy refer to the same sequence nextval twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to utilize SQLAlchemy's ORM [`after_insert`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.after_insert) mapper event:

```
from sqlalchemy import event

# Model from OP
class Foo(Base):
    pk = Column(Integer, Sequence('foo'), primary_key=True)
    ref = Column(Integer, index=True, nullable=False, default=-1)

    @staticmethod
    def fill_ref(mapper, connection, target):
        # Note: You cannot use ORM in the event callbacks
        connection.execute(mapper.mapped_table.update()
                                 .values(ref=target.pk))
                                 .where(table.c.pk==target.pk))

event.listen(Foo, 'after_insert', Foo.fill_ref)
```

Comment: Cool, I tried this and it worked. One question though--how come I have access to the `pk` attribute here? I'm used to it not appearing until after I commit, but I guess my model of sqlalchemy isn't complete here.

Comment: @BenKuhn 'after_insert' event is emitted just after ORM receives the object from the DB after the 'INSERT'. This means that all the db-side processing and triggers have been called. There's also a **big fat warning** to not use code that modifies `Session` so you have fall back to using `connection` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a trigger to set that value. Though I haven't tested this myself, you could have a trigger activate AFTER INSERT that reads the new row's PK value and update the ref column with that value. It seems somewhat similar to [Postgresql insert trigger to set value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102188/postgresql-insert-trigger-to-set-value) except that you want the trigger to be after the insert, instead of before.