# How to do a Django like post_save signal with Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'd like to notice whenever a model is saved and then do some processing and save another model. I need the model to already have an ID set by the database in the processing stage.

With Django one would override the `.save()` method of model or use signals like:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save 
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import MyModel, OtherModel

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def do_stuff(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    assert instance.id is not None
    ...
    OtherModel.create(related=instance, data=...)
```

How to do similar with `SQLAlchemy` and `Flask`? I looked up [ORM Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html) and it seemed that `expire` IntanceEvent would fit the bill. It seems to fire whenever a model instance is saved but when I try to do the same kind of thing:

```
from sqlalchemy import event

from . import db
from .models import MyModel, OtherModel

@event.listens_for(MyModel, "expire")
def do_stuff(target, attrs):
    assert target.id is not None
    ...
    db.session.add(OtherModel(related=target, data=...))
    db.session.commit()
```

It fails on `assert instance.id is not None` with:

```
InvalidRequestError: This session is in 'committed' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction.
```

It might be that I'm just approaching this the wrong way or I'm missing something crucial but I cannot figure it out. The documentation is split among `Flask`, `Flask-SQLAlchemy` and `SQLAlchemy` and I have hard time piecing this together.

How should I make this kind of post save trigger with `SQLAlchemy`?

Answer (score 3):

The event you want to listen for is 'after_insert', not 'expire':

```
@event.listens_for(MyModel, 'after_insert')
def do_stuff(mapper, connection, target):
    assert target.id is not None
    ...
```

Also, after creating `OtherModel` inside the listener and calling `db.session.add`, don't call `db.session.commit` as it will throw a `ResourceClosedError` exception.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277403/how-can-i-create-a-sqlalchemy-column-whose-default-is-to-be-equal-to-the-primary) which gives an example of using SQLAlchemy's after_insert mapper event.  It should do what you want, but using raw SQL rather than your session object is recommended.