# Ignore column on PostgreSQL view insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

A library that I use currently has a bug and I'm trying to find a workaround for. Is it possible to to ignore a column on a PostgreSQL view insert? I have this view:

```
CREATE VIEW schema.auth AS
  SELECT email AS id, pass AS pass, 'onymous'::varchar AS rolname
    FROM schema.person;
```

The library is trying to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO schema.auth (id, pass, rolname) VALUES ('abc', '123', '');
```

The library should not be setting an empty string (`''`) for `rolname`, hence the bug.

Is there a way for me to stop PostgreSQL from throwing an error at `rolname` and quietly discard the empty string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgresql insert trigger to set value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102188/postgresql-insert-trigger-to-set-value)

Comment: It is my understanding that triggers don't work that way on views.

Comment: Yes. I tried adding a trigger before inserts/updates. Even then though, I'm still not sure how to remove a column.

Comment: You can replace the empty string with a value that will not cause the bug, e.g. NULL

Comment: I don't have access to the empty string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually very trivial. What you do is simply "forget" `rolname` when propagating the `INSERT` on the view to the underlying tables:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fix_lib_issue() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO schema.person (email, pass)
  VALUES NEW.id, NEW.pass;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_auth
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON schema.auth
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fix_lib_issue();
```

When you query the view after the insert, the `rolname` will be set to `onymous`,  following the view definition.