# Simple trigger combining TG_TABLE_NAME and now() SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I'd like to have one trigger function to update `<table_name>.date_updated` to `now()`. I'm using `TG_TABLE_NAME` in the `update` statement, as I have many tables that would call this trigger function. However - I'm missing something basic as I get the error `relation "tg_table_name" does not exist` whenever I attempt to `\copy` data into my tables.

Here is my trigger function:

```
create or replace function table_updated() 
returns trigger as 
$body$
begin 
    update TG_TABLE_NAME
    set NEW.date_updated = now();
end
$body$
language plpgsql;

create trigger "updateDate"
before update or insert on <table_name>
for each row execute procedure table_updated();
```

I'm using Postgres version 10.5.

If I understand this correctly I need to somehow implement `execute`, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I guess you'd need dynamic SQL creating a query targeting the name in the variable as a string and then execute it. But do you really want to update **every** row? You have no `WHERE` in the `UPDATE` query. Typically the changed or inserted row is changed by a trigger. But that can be done via the `NEW` record.

Comment: Are you just looking to set `NEW.date_updated = now()`?  Take a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102188/postgresql-insert-trigger-to-set-value

Comment: I totally neglected to add in the `NEW` when typing this up - thanks for pointing that out! What I'm hoping to do is to avoid making 15 functions, 15 triggers for each table - I'd rather have 1 function, 15 triggers. I just don't know how to reference the table trigger generically/dynamically within the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is ridiculously simple but leaving this up for other people just starting out with databases in case they have the same issue. You don't need to specify the table that's being updated within the function, as the trigger is already assigned to said table. It knows it's referencing/updating itself.

```
create or replace function table_updated() 
returns trigger as 
$body$
begin 
    new.date_updated = now();
    return new;
end
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

If anybody can explain this more logically than I just did, please feel free to correct me!