# How to avoid empty strings in db?

Tags: spring, postgresql

I have a REST API written in Spring that inserts data into a PostgreSQL database. I would like to avoid empty strings in the database -- and let empty fields be null instead.

Is there anything meaningful I can do in the database side?

For instance, I tried this and while the syntax works from the console, it won't work with named parameters when used by JdbcTemplate in Spring.

```
insert
...
nullif(trim(:value), '')
```

Or perhaps I should just clean the data programmatically?

---

Edit: To clarify, I am asking about the concepts, *not* about the specific way of achieving the goal provided as an *example*, or the resulting error message.

Comment: "it won't work with named parameters when used by JdbcTemplate in Spring" -- You should [edit] he question and provide a [example] of such an issue and the exact error message.

Comment: The minimal reproducible example is this: 'nullif(trim(:value), '')'.
':value' is the named parameter.

Comment: That is **not** a [example]!

Comment: That's an example of what I'm asking about. Of course I can wrap the example in entire application, but that's not the code I'm asking about. In fact, I'm not asking about any existing code at all, but about how this can / should be done.

Comment: A [example] is required and it's not a [example]. Read the definition behind the link. And the error message is also still missing.

Comment: Yeah that's it. That's 100% of the code that does the thing included in the question. But this is an EXAMPLE of how things can be done. There cannot logically exist anything reproducible when asking how things SHOULD or COULD be done, which is what the question is about.

Comment: This was enough for me to know that he needs a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102188/postgresql-insert-trigger-to-set-value

Comment: Perfect, thanks @AaronBell