# How to create a trigger in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I need to create a trigger in postgres where, when I add a record to table A, it automatically inserts its primary key value (which is auto incremented) into table B, the primary key of table A is the foreign key in table B.

I have tried doing it through pgadmin but it does not allow me to save. Could someone help out please.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: all you need to do is read the documentation https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/everything-you-need-know-about-postgresql-triggers

Comment: and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102188/postgresql-insert-trigger-to-set-value

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: 1) It is spelled out in the docs [plpgsql triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). 2) Not sure what the purpose of this is? Without the rest of the row in table B filled in having just the FK does not really do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create the following trigger function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auto_insert() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO
        B(a_id)
        VALUES(new.id);

           RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

And then attach the trigger function to table A.

```
CREATE TRIGGER auto_inserter
 AFTER INSERT ON A
 FOR EACH ROW
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE auto_insert();
```